# Where is a mistake equating $x$ derived from both equations of a system?

Tags: systems-of-equations, rational-functions, symmetric-functions

[image]

I know how to solve this, but why is the below reasoning wrong and leads to a mistake (I don't see any mistake!)

Step 1: From first equation $x=\dfrac{8}{y}$ , and $y$ is not zero

Step 2: From second equation $\dfrac{1}{x}=\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{y}\to\dfrac{1}{x}=\dfrac{y+1}{4y}\to x=\dfrac{4y}{y+1}$

Step 3: equate same $x$ from Step 1 and step 2: $\dfrac{8}{y}=\dfrac{4y}{y+1}$ , and $y$ is not $-1$ , but solving this for $y$ gives wrong result.

Where is the mistake in steps above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is in the second step. In fact, it is
$$\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{y} = \frac{y+4}{4y}$$

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for my being stupid. I just got afraid my method was conceptually wrong...

Comment: @user10777718 don't worry, that can happen :) there's nothing conceptually wrong.